# Editing with ArcGIS API for Silveright?

Tags: arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, editing, arcgis-silverlight-api

I am using the ArcGIS Silverlight API to edit data in an ArcSDE SQL Server geodatabase.

I have been told that any editable feature classes must be registered as versioned in ArcCatalog before they can be edited via the Silverlight API.

Does anyone know why this is the case?  From what I understand, you can not use the Silverlight API to edit versioned data in a feature class, so I'm not clear on why you would have to register the feature classes as versioned.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what the [online doc](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/help/arcgis_server_dotnet_help/index.html#/Authoring_feature_services/009300000021000000/) says:

> Versioned and unversioned data is
>   supported; however, versioning is
>   required if you plan on editing
>   nonsimple types (for example, network
>   edges) with the service.

Also verify that the Editor has been [configured for non-versioned editing](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/help/arcgis_server_dotnet_help/index.html#//0093000015zv000000.htm).

Comment: As far as I know, the Silverlight API is requiring it for all types.  The feature class I'm editing on is just points.

Comment: Non-versioned data is supported.  From the ArcGIS SLAPI help (and I've personally used SL to edit non-versioned feature classes) 
http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/help/index.html#/Editing/016600000017000000/ 
"The ArcGIS Silverlight/WPF API provides simple feature editing. The features must come from an ArcSDE geodatabase hosted in an ArcGIS Server feature service. This geodatabase can be licensed for either workgroup or enterprise use and does not have to be versioned"

Comment: @Seth - To troubleshoot, I'd try this: rightclick on arcmap from the startup menu and choose "run as",  enter the credentials of the arcgissoc user account.  Start editing and see if you can edit.  If you can't edit you either need to grant privs to the arcgissoc account or use dbms authentication for the arcsde connection.

Comment: @wwnick I did try editing on a non-versioned feature class.  I was able to make edits, but not save them using the Silverlight template provided by ESRI.  Once I made the feature class versioned, it worked correctly.

Comment: @seth - did fiddler show any errors when you tried to save?